# Custom InfoWindowAdapter is not calling from onMarkerClick()

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I set `CustomInfoWindow` to call when user click on maker. I do not call it when create `Map` but call only when user clicks on a `Marker`.

I have different overlays and those has different infoWindows implementation 
Overlay class build the `infoWindow` like below.

```
public  void onTap(AndroidMapOverlayItem item) {

  String overlayType = "";

  googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

 /*
  * some code to find overlayType
  */

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if ("mylocation".equalsIgnoreCase(overlayType)) {


                // set title
                ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Title");

                // set distance
                ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(display);

            }
            return infoWindow;

        }
    });
 }
```

Below is my activity class that pick the user clicks and find the which marker. Based on the marker I call its relevant overlay class. That overlay class has what information to show in infowindow.
Activity class.

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);        

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside onMakerClick "+marker);


    /*
             * find the relevant overlay class and try to fire it's onTap event.
             * onTap event has what needs to be done with specific marker.
             * Different marker has different information to show.
             *
             */
    overlay.onTap(overlayItem);


    return true;

}
```

This I wanted because when I set CustomInfowindow at first instance all the markers shows the same infomation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fix it. Now I see different information when I click on each marker.

I add following code after `overlay.onTap(overlayItem)` in `onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)`

```
    if (!marker.isInfoWindowShown())
        marker.showInfoWindow();
```